# stop messages from showing in informix on a unix platform using perl

Tags: perl, unix, informix

I'm writing a Perl script that uses some database functions using system command since I can't use DBI module

```
`db query.sql`
```

The thing is I don't want the database messages to show like

```
database opened

table created


database closed
```

the database is informix

Thank you :)

Comment: What program is this 'db' ? Custom or comes with Informix?

Comment: when executing db, it's equivalent to dbaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to discard all messages

```
`db query.sql > /dev/null 2>&1`
```

Use this to discard warnings, errors & messages printed out on STDERR

```
`db query.sql 2> /dev/null`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
`db query.sql > /dev/null`
```